# Simple reading file using ReadFile()

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode, byte-order-mark

Why this code doesn't output anything(exept info word)? File is exist.

```
hReadFile = CreateFile(L"indexing.xml",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ |FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    wchar_t *wchr = new wchar_t[20];
    DWORD dw;
    ReadFile(hReadFile, wchr, sizeof(wchar_t) * 5, &dw, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hReadFile);
    wchr[dw/sizeof(wchar_t)] = L'\0';
    std::wcout << L"info " << wchr << L"     " << dw << std::endl;
```

Comment: To start with, you don't terminate the string you read.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Doesn't ReadFile terminate reading data automaticaly?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: the output would be the string followed by a garbage

Comment: What does debugger show for `wchr` after `ReadFile`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg There is even garbage absent. I've tried to add wchar_t[5] = '\0' but it doesn't help

Comment: What did you expect the code to do?  You read 5 characters from a file...  Or did you?  It's possible that the file could not be opened, or the read failed.  You did not test.

Comment: @Andrey Debugger says that in wchar exist data L"<?xm췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍﷽﷽ꮫꮫꮫꮫﻮﻮ"

Comment: Many possible reasons but by far the most likely is that you don't open the file successfully. **Always** test whether you open a file, there are many reasons why this might not work.

Comment: @Vsevywniy OK you haven't terminated the data read. `wchr[dw] = 0;`

Comment: @john I've used code that view in edit quetion, look at it, but result the same

Comment: It should be `wchr[dw/sizeof(wchar_t)] = 0` assuming everything succeeded.

Comment: @ybungalobill also wrong

Comment: @Vsevywniy: I have not said that it would solve the problem. The *real* problem is that you use `ReadFile` instead of `ifstream` and UTF-16 instead of UTF-8. I know, [Unicode on windows sucks](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: The `ReadFile` function doesn't know what it's reading, for the function the file is just a stream of bytes and it doesn't know or care about any structure, it's up to you to impose structure (like terminating strings read from a file).

Comment: I think problem in console output stream encoding, but how can i correct change it? I try to use std::wcout.imbue(std::locale::global(std::locale(""))); but it doesn't help

Comment: What is the value of `dw` after having returned from `ReadFile()`? Is it different from 0;

Comment: Problem with Unicode strings (wide char). It reads successfully in "char". And nothing to do with locale as your XML is plain ASCII (i suppose).

Comment: If you want to read UTF-8 file in wide char (wchar_t) strings (UTF-16 on Windows) you would have to use MultiByteToWideChar to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16 (wchar_t) and WideCharToMuliByte to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Comment: @SChepurin encoding of xml file is unicode UTF16

Comment: Would `std::wcout << L"info " << (wchr+1) << L"     " << dw << std::endl;` print what you expect?

Comment: @alk ye it works, thanks, but why (wchr+1)?

Comment: In the OP's case it's a 2-byte BOM. See my answer for details. @Vsevywniy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Unicode file might start with an optional [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

For UTF-16 the BOM tells which endianess is used in the the file.

Also the BOM can be used to destinguish between different Unicode encodings.

The example file from the OP obviously carries such a BOM as its first two bytes, as increasing the pointer (to the 2-byte sized `wchar_t` typed array) skips it and lets the data be printed.

```
std::wcout << L"info " << (wchr+1) << L" " << dw << std::endl;
```