# Reading unicode file

Tags: c++, c

Why next code give an error? Look code and pictures. How to fix it
[image]

```
wchar_t *GetLine(wchar_t *fileName=L"indexing.xml", wchar_t endSymbol = '\n')
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int sz;
    _wfopen_s(&file, fileName, L"r");
    std::wifstream fs (file);
    int size;
    wchar_t wchr[1];
    size = 0;
    do
    {
        sz = fread(&wchr,sizeof(wchar_t),1,file);
        if(!sz)
        {
            break;
        }
        tempGetLine[size] = wchr[0];
        size++;
    }while(wchr[0] != endSymbol);
    tempGetLine[size] = '\0';
    position += (size);
    fs.close();
    return tempGetLine;
}
```

but this work correct

```
wchar_t *GetLine(wchar_t *fileName=L"indexing.xml", wchar_t endSymbol = '\n')
{
    hReadFile = CreateFileW(L"indexing.xml",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ |FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    SetFilePointer(hReadFile,sizeof(wchar_t) * position, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    int size;
    wchar_t wchr[1];
    DWORD dw;
    size = 0;
    do
    {
        ReadFile(hReadFile, wchr, sizeof(wchar_t), &dw, NULL);
        if(!dw)
        {
            break;
        }
        tempGetLine[size] = wchr[0];
        size++;
    }while(wchr[0] != endSymbol);
    tempGetLine[size] = '\0';
    position += (size);
    return tempGetLine;
}
```

[image]
Full code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>
int position = 0;
wchar_t tempGetLine[500];
wchar_t *GetLine(wchar_t *fileName=L"indexing.xml", wchar_t endSymbol = '\n')
{
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int sz;
    _wfopen_s(&file, L"C:\\indexing.xml", L"r");
    std::wifstream fs (file);
    int x = GetLastError();
    fseek(file,sizeof(wchar_t) * position,SEEK_SET);
    int size;
    wchar_t wchr[1];
    size = 0;
    do
    {
        sz = fread(&wchr,sizeof(wchar_t),1,file);
        if(!sz)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(wchr[0] >= L'А')continue;            //Only for console application
        tempGetLine[size] = wchr[0];
        size++;
    }while(wchr[0] != endSymbol);
    tempGetLine[size] = '\0';
    position += (size);
    fs.close();
    return tempGetLine;
}
```

Comment: @hyde line 102 is in the Microsoft C runtime.

Comment: @hyde that would line 102 inside the fread.c library; unimportant for this question.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is that (file) is NULL, of course, most likely because the file doesn't exist, or is located in another directory.

Comment: Follow the call stack back to *your* code. That will shine some light on the problem.

Comment: If you haven't used the debugger before now is a good time to start. If you run your program in a debugger, when it crashes you will see a _call stack_, where you can find out _where_ in your code the crash is. Once you are in your code, you can examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

Comment: There are other unusual features about your code too. Can you explain, for instance, why you have `int size;` in one line and then `size = 0;` two lines down? I'd like to hear your reasoning.

Comment: Well one difference between the working code and the non-working code is that the working code opens a file called "indexing.xml" but the non-working code opens whatever is in the `filename` variable. Maybe the `filename` variable has the wrong value. As Joachim says you should use a debugger to narrow down your problem.

Comment: @john when i use L"indexing.xml" instead fileName pointer i get the same error

Comment: Oh Vsevywniy! Why, tell me, *why* are you keep trying to use wide-chars!?

Comment: My 2 cents : is'nt it that wfopen does'nt honnor current working directory correctly?Try to use absolute paths port the wfopen version

Comment: @ybungalobill I use this code in win32 application for output date to window(this console version only for testing), so i think i can use wchar_T

Comment: @Vsevywniy: you can, but you don't have to. Reading/writing widechars to external sources is painful, even working with them internally is painful. A much simpler approach is to store UTF-8 inside your files and convert it to wide-chars when you actually displaying it in the window.\

Comment: @ybungalobill - Please, take a look at "solution" he got for the similar question he asked before "Simple reading file using ReadFile()" -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046140/simple-reading-file-using-readfile. I can't see how this second sample can "work correct".

Comment: @SChepurin I'm knowing it, it's my question. In this sample i use xml file without BOM. Problem in _wfopen_s function, when i'm debugging code it shows that after invoke _wfopen_s file still uninitiallized. I don't know how can i combine _wfopen_s with fread function. First need FILE** as argument, but second need FILE*. May be you have some idea.

Comment: @Vsevywniy: You call the `_wfopen_s` correctly. Make sure that the file isn't open by another part of your code, or by other programs. Check the return value of `_wfopen_s`. Check the return value of `GetLastError()`.

Comment: @ybungalobill return vale 0x00000000 {_ptr=??? _cnt=??? _base=??? ...} GetLastError() 2

Comment: @Vsevywniy GetLastError() == 2 means 'file not found' Are you really, really sure that the path is correct?

Comment: @john ye, see preent screen of file system in edition of question

Comment: @Vsevywniy are you sure your program is executing in the directory you expect? Try a full path.

Comment: @AlanStokes ye it's current project directory. I've tried full path, it's the same result

Comment: @Vsevywniy I wrote a small program using `_wfopen_s` on a file in the project directory. It worked for me. What happens if you try the same?

Comment: @john I've tried it I get the same error. look full code in editionof question at a moment

Comment: @Vsevywniy: "C:\\indexing.xml"??? if this is the full path you tried then it is incorrect, since you say that the file is in the project directory.

Comment: @ybungalobill O ye it's my fault, sorry for this stupid mistake, I've edited it. It works for small single project, but what can be in complex project it still get an error?

Comment: O i fixed it it HANDLE to this file was opened. Thanks so much to all, specially thanks for ybungalobill and john

Comment: @Vsevywniy: Did you edit the question to correct the problem you were asking about? Please don't do that; it makes the question useless to future readers. If you want to say how the problem was solved, add a comment to the question, or better yet, to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has failed to open for some reason and `file` is NULL. **Always** check that files open.

Also got to wonder what you think you are doing with `fs`.

Comment: Why is it NULL? File is exist in file system. What wrong in my code?

Comment: I have no idea. Your method of opening your file is unusual. But there are many, many reasons a file can fail to open. Most common being that the place the program is looking for the file is not the place that you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for file `indexing.xml` in the current directory.

The default for a VC project is the current directory set to the directory of the exe file, `2012\Projects\FindPattern\Debug`. The file is not there, it is one folder up.

Comment: Actually file is in folder 2012\Projects\FindPattern\FindPattern(look at snapshot). I've already searched it. Thanks for reply.